# Facebook login throws URL not allowed error in WWW version of my website

Tags: facebook, .htaccess, authentication, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

In the Facebook application settings I have set the Site URL as `http://www.sitename.com` and in App domains I have set as `sitename.com`.

But when I open the website as `www.sitename.com` to Login with Facebook it throws the **Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration** error. But when I try without WWW it works perfect. How to resolve this error?

And in my .htaccess to make the website WWW version I use this code,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sitename.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.sitename.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

**Edit**

Since I could not solve this the problem I decided to make the page `login.php` alone to be non-WWW version. This means when a visitor opens `domain.com` or `domain.com/my-page` it must be redirected to `www.domain.com` or `www.domain.com/my-page` except the page `login.php`. So even if the user enters `www.domain.com/login.php` it must forcefully redirect to `domain.com/login.php`. I could not figure out the *Redirect Except* condition for this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how your .htaccess should look like:

```
RewriteEngine On

# add www except for /login.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sitename\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/login\.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.sitename.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# remove www for /login.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.sitename\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(login\.php)$ http://sitename.com/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: The `login.php` is just a sample. Actually it was a rewritten url as `sitename.com/register-an-account` with `RewriteRule    ^register-an-account    login.php    [NC]    # Registration page and Sign In` So now when entered without www it is directly redirected to login.php. And if I enter the url as `www.sitename.com/login.php` it is not redirected to `http://sitename.com/login.php`

Comment: Please, update your question with actual htaccess details. The rules are interacting with each other because you haven't used `[L]` flags for them.

Comment: With a slight modification in your answer I achieved the task.

1. I have used the conditions for add www except for login.php

2. In the login.php (actually rewritten as register-an-account), I use this login `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` and if the 1st 3 characters are www I user `header` redirect to non www version.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted.